# Pasar variable del controlador hacia la vista

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de sacar el resultado de una consulta hacia la vista, estoy realizando un ejemplo sencillo de esta manera, pero igual no muestra la información que tiene en el controlador

controller.php

```
public function mostrarInfoTienda(){
    $prueba="pruebaaaaaaa";
}
```

y en la visto lo llamo asi:

```
 $ver = new Controller();
 $prueba = $ver -> mostrarInfoTienda();

echo "esta es la variable". $prueba;
```

Comment: Te falta `return $prueba;` en la función `mostrarInfoTienda()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function mostrarInfoTienda(){
    $prueba="pruebaaaaaaa";

    return $prueba;
}
```

en la vista

```
$ver = new Controller();
$prueba = $ver -> mostrarInfoTienda();
echo "esta es la variable". $prueba;
```